# How can i keep a value I receive from base controller for other methods?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Controller, that Inherets from a Base Controller. The Base Controller takes an argument and decides what option to return. I would like to have access to the returned values for other methods in the Controllers class, but in other methods they are null.

I've tried assigning the return value to a field, but with no success. What is the best way to set a 'global' variable based on what the BaseController returns?

```
                                            //RockController//
public class RockController : BaseController
{
  string currentlySelectedRegion;

  public ActionResult Rocks(string selectedRock)
  {
    currentlySelectedRegion = setResources(selectedRock)
    return View(viewModel);
  }

  public ActionResult RockColor()
  {
    // so some other stuff with currentlySelectedRegion
  }
}


                                            //BaseController//
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  protected string currentlySelectedRegion;

  public void setResources(string selectedRock)
  {
    if(selectedRock == "red")
  {
    currentlySelectedRegion = "desert"
  } else {
    currentlySelectedRegion = "not a desert"
  }
}
```

Comment: BaseController doesn't define currentlySelectedRegion' So setting currentlySelectedRegion to something in setResources will be a compile error. Also setResources doesn't return anything. Se setting currentlySelectedRegion to setResource in the action Rocks will also be a compile error. Try changing return type for setResources to string then return "desert" or return "not a desert".

Comment: The controller is instantiated every time an HTTP API endpoint is called.

Comment: The server side for your web application (ie. your controllers) should be stateless. Do not try to maintain state server side for actions the caller is doing across requests. Pass in any state required with every call from the client. There are some exceptions to this rule but treat them as just that, exceptions. This is how mvc / web api / asp.net core was designed to be used.

Comment: @SkyeMacMaster good point on currentlySelectedRegion. I changed the code for privacy and slipped on that - it's edited now.

Comment: @Igor - good to know, so in that case i should make a call to the basecontroller every time i need that info?

Comment: Pass the state back to the caller. How you do that is up to you and/or your application architecture. One example could be to store it in a cookie, then it is also available server side with the next request. Another is to pass it in the http header and then have the client extract it and send it back if you need it for another call. Or return it as the http message body and take it in subsequent methods as a query string or http message body parameter. Or make it a hidden input field value in a form. There are many options for communicating between client/server.